# Восстановление БД с помощью логов транзакций вешает БД в состояние Restoring

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

В общем, каждый день выполняется полный бекап БД и каждые N часов бекапятся логи транзакций.

Так вот, допустим если бекап логов выполнился в 10 часов, а следующий бекап в 12 часов, то при попытке восстановить БД на 11 часов средствами `SSMS`, то он  позволяет выбрать это время, а потом пишет об успешности, однако, БД по факту продолжает висеть в состоянии Restoring. Если дождаться бекапов логов и выполнить  восстановление по новой, то все успешно восстановится.

Такое поведение нормально или где-то есть какая-то настройка, которая позволит восстановить БД не дожидаясь бекапа лога?

На сколько я знаю, если каких-то логов не хватает, то он бы мне не позволит выбрать дату ниже определенной.

Вот такой скрипт мне генерит SSMS:

```
RESTORE DATABASE [BD] FROM  DISK = N'BD_20190521040008.bak' WITH  FILE = 1,  NORECOVERY,  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
GO
RESTORE LOG [BD] FROM  DISK = N'BD_20190521080006.trn' WITH  FILE = 1,  NORECOVERY,  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10,  STOPAT = N'2019-05-21T11:46:31'
GO
RESTORE LOG [BD] FROM  DISK = N'BD_20190521103001.trn' WITH  FILE = 1,  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10,  STOPAT = N'2019-05-21T11:46:31'
GO
```

Comment: Добавьте к вопросу команду, которой выполняется восстановление

Comment: @DenisRubashkin через интерфейс SSMS. Правой кнопкой по бд tasks=>restore и там все само подгружается. Я лишь дату выбираю и название БД в которую нужно выполнить восстановление.

Comment: В интерфейсе SSMS есть кнопка Script (в левом верхнем углу), которая сформирует команду

Comment: @DenisRubashkin добавил.

Answer (score 3):

Из документации (на русском не нашел) [docs.microsoft.com](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/restore-a-sql-server-database-to-a-point-in-time-full-recovery-model?view=sql-server-2017)

> The RECOVERY and STOPAT options. If the transaction log backup does
>   not contain the requested time (for example, if the time specified is
>   beyond the end of the time covered by the transaction log), a warning
>   is generated and the database remains unrecovered.

**Перевод:**

> Опции RECOVERY и STOPAT. Если резервная копия журнала транзакций не
>   содержит запрошенного времени (например, **если указанное время
>   превышает время, указанное в журнале транзакций**), генерируется
>   предупреждение, и **база данных остается невосстановленной**.

То есть, в вашем случае, чтобы восстановить базу не дожидаясь следующего бекапа лога транзакций, нужно выполнить команду

```
RESTORE DATABASE databasename WITH RECOVERY
```

Comment: По факту там не будет запрошенного мною времени?

Comment: Нет, конечно же, там будут данные на момент последнего бекапа лога транзакций. Откуда бекап, который создается в 10:00, может знать какие транзакции будут выполнены в будущем до 11:00?

Comment: Ну т.е из незабекапленного лога прозаимствовать недостающую информацию нельзя?

Comment: Ну, почему нельзя, можно - забекапить его и потом восстановиться из этого бекапа.

Comment: Так-то да, но я думал что все таки имеется какой-то еще способ.

Comment: [На русском](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/restore-a-sql-server-database-to-a-point-in-time-full-recovery-model?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 1):

Состояние Restoring может быть, а не Restore? Тогда это нормальное состояние, если вы в диалоге не выбрали опцию with recovery. Оно позволяет накатить на базу последующие бэкапы логов.

Вывод из него:

```
 RESTORE DATABASE databasename WITH RECOVERY
```

Comment: Добавил скрипт в вопрос.

Comment: Т.е WITH RECOVERY накатит еще и тот лог, который не бекапился?

Comment: @iluxa1810 нет, естественно, в базе будет только то, что есть в тех файлах, которые вы восстанавливали. With recovery просто уведет базу в нормальное состояние.

Comment: @iluxa1810 состоияние recovery позволяет донести потом и довосстановить ещё логи. Сами по себе данные не материализуются на сервере из другой базы с помощью магии :)